# Heterogeneous Dictionary, but typed?

Tags: .net

This is more of an academic inquiry than a practical question.  Are there any language or framework features that can, or will in future, allow a heterogeneous typed dcitionary, e.g.

```
myDict.Add("Name", "Bill"); 
myDict.Add("Height", 1.2);
```

where myDict now contains not two `object` types as values, but one `string` and one `double`?  I could then retrieve my `double` with

```
double dbl = myDict["Height"];
```

and expect a double or an exception to be thrown?

Please note:  The Name and Height values are not necessarily of the same object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only way you'll be able to do this if you have a custom collection with generic overloads for Add and Get methods. But that would mean you can ask for the wrong type when reading the key out, so it doesn't gain you much (if anything) over doing the cast yourself when you call your Get method.

However, if you can push the generic type into the key then that could work. Something like (untested code here)

```
sealed class MyDictionaryKey<T>
{
}

class MyDictionary
{
    private Dictionary<object, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<object, object>();

    public void Add<T>(MyDictionaryKey<T> key, T value)
    {
        dictionary.Add(key, value);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue<T>(MyDictionaryKey<T> key, out T value)
    {
      object objValue;
      if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out objValue))
      {
        value = (T)objValue;
        return true;
      }
      value = default(T);
      return false;
    }

    public T Get<T>(MyDictionaryKey<T> key)
    {
      T value;
      if (!TryGetValue(key, out value))
         throw new KeyNotFoundException();
      return value;
    }
}
```

Then you can define your keys like:

```
static readonly MyDictionaryKey<string> NameKey = new MyDictionaryKey<string>();
static readonly MyDictionaryKey<double> HeightKey = new MyDictionaryKey<double>();
```

and use it like

```
var myDict = new MyDictionary();
myDict.Add(NameKey, "Bill"); // this will take a string
myDict.Add(HeightKey , 1.2); // this will take a double

string name = myDict.Get(NameKey); // will return a string
double height = myDict.Get(HeightKey); // will return a double
```

Comment: Thank you.  As others have said, this is less of a practical than academic inquiry, but you hit the head on the nail in inferring that I wanted the key to determine the expected type of the item retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Generic `Dictionary<object, object>`; object type for key and object type for value. C# could help.

Answer (score 1):

The keys are all strings? then `Dictionary<string,object>` would probably do the job... but when getting values out, you would either need to use `object`, or you'd need to cast:

```
double dbl = (double)myDict["Height"];
object height = myDict["Height"];
```

Comment: The very reason I asked the question was to avoid having dic values as objects.  If I store a double, I want a double back, not a 'double exposing object' that I must cast.

Comment: @Profk - you are fooling yourself if you think that Get<int>(...) is any different to (int) Get(...). Oh well...

Comment: @MarcGravell not true. If the class is internally enforcing the association between a type and its value on insert, then a retrieval that requires an internal cast would be completely safe (not compiler safe, but safe assuming the code is internally correct). No external caller would be *able* to cause an invalid cast based on key/value type mismatch. They would either get a typed value, or they would get a null back, and it would be completely type safe from their perspective. In theory no invalid cast exceptions would ever occur, not inside the container, nor outside the container.

Comment: @AaronHS I fail to see how that makes any difference whatsoever; in that case, both `(int)Get(...)` and `Get<int>(...)` would work, but they *already* worked (or not) together. All we've done is move the cast. Handing a null back because somebody got the type wrong is a bad move; the *correct* thing to do there is: an invalid cast exception.

Comment: @MarcGravell problem isn't that `somebody got the type wrong`. The problem is that someone naively associated a key with a value of one type, say `string`: (1) `dict.Add("myKey!", "myStringValue!")`. Then later, the same someone attempts to retrieve that value: (2) `string unsafeStr = (string)dict["myKey!"]` and **bang** cast exception occurs. But why? Some other one, thought that `myKey!` is a great key for an `int` value, and somewhere between (1) and (2), this line of code was executed: `dict["myKey!"] = 123`. Here, `(string)Get` fails however `Get<String>` succeeds and retains consistency.

Comment: @yair and I maintain that the **best thing that can happen here** is the failure, to alert you to the problem; very rarely do good things come from ignoring problems.

Comment: @MarcGravell as I come from Java, I must say that the separated methods for adding a new value or overwriting an existing one to the dictionary - may be of big assist to prevent the case I mentioned in the previous comment, though. In Java the same `put` method is responsible for both and is therefore more prone to this kind of error. So in C# I'm really not sure the hassle is worth the little gain in type-safety.

Comment: @MarcGravell I agree generally. The reason behind writing such a special utility class should not be a faint attempt at preventing some improbable error (or probable), but because it adds some necessary functionality that is missing from the core libraries. So +1! (I've spent hours now figuring out the best solution)

Answer (score 1):

If the types are classes there's nothing to stop you interfacing both and putting the instances in a dictionary <foo, IYourInterface>

Comment: Maybe.  Maybe something like IPresentationElementValue.  Food for thought.

Answer (score 1):

A Dictionary is not the way to do it.
You really want a Person class for storing those values.

And, it is much easier to both create collections and catch errors with classes.

**EDIT:**

Since you need a semi-strongly typed dict:

```
public class CustomDictionary : Dictionary<string,object>
{
    public T GetTyped<T>(string key) where T : IConvertible
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(base[key], typeof (T));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
CustomDictionary dictionary = new CustomDictionary();

dictionary.Add("Test",1.2);

var d = dictionary.GetTyped<double>("Test");
```

Comment: The values need not be coupled to the same object, as my example accidentally implied.  Name could be that of a dog, and Height that of a table.

Comment: Oh, ok. You want a CustomDictonary that extends Dictionary<string,object> and Adds a GetTyped<Type>(string key) method :)

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you can't make a class / struct and put that into a list or dictionary? Otherwise you could just wrap the dictionary class with your own and put the restrictions in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply store all values as strings, convert them when you retrieve them, and catch exceptions from that conversion?

I don't see why you would need to do things this way - perhaps a redesign of your program is warranted?

Comment: I don't need to do things this way.  I don't need to do anything except explore what could be done.

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary WILL contain a string and a double as values, but the double will be boxed.

How could the compiler validate what you're asking? How could it know at compile time which type of object relates to each key?

Comment: The idea is not to know at compile time, but to use the key to determine the return type.  C# is moving toward including some exciting dynamic concepts, and I believe this could fall under the shadow of that.