# List of generic delegates (e.g. System.Converter<TInput, TOutput>)

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible to create a list of generic delegates, like `System.Converter<TInput, TOutput>`?

In java that could be `List<Converter<?,?>>`, but with Java's type erasure that's not very useful. Seems like in C# it should be possible to query the generic types after retrieval from the list and use the obtained instance to perform the desired conversion.

**Elaborating on the question:**
I have user supplied data in user provided formats which I know nothing about at compile time. Algorithms in my program know how to work with its own specific data types, of course. The goal is to have an equiavalent of Java's `List<Converter<?,?>>` where Converters can be installed (by me, or users) and queried automatically by the program to see if user's data can be converted to the required format for an algorithm.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to do/ what you already attempted to do and formulate a question?

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit fuzzy on what's being asked here too.

Comment: @MindSwipe Like the first sentence says, I'm attempting to create a `List<Converter<?,?>>` (or, preferably a `Dictionary<TIn, Converter<TIn, ?>>`), which I can query for presence of Converters for user's data type to other data types.

Comment: You can, using `List<Delegate>`, but it's not very useful as such because you "lose" the type information unless you can reconstitute it. If you store them in a dictionary keyed on their type arguments, then you can have a generic method with those type arguments, look up the delegate, cast it, and use it.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you want a list of converters, which you can query to see for which types converters are implemented?

Comment: You don't need `Dictionary<T, Something<T>>`, because that probably will be used inside some generic method. Just use `Something<T>` directly. It would be really cool if you add a short code demonstrating your problem into a question.

Comment: @MindSwipe I updated the question a little. And yes, your understanding is correct. Right now I'm using a custom interface, that requires implementors to specify data type in, data type out, and the conversion method itself with signature `object Convert(object)`. I then store instances of those "converters" in a dictionary and check/cast everythig myself, which is tedious and error prone. I though maybe C# syntax and lack of erasure allows to solve this.

Comment: @madreflection This sounds very much like what I'd want to do. Seems like the key ingredient here is the "generic method with those type arguments"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very rudimentary and is only intended to show the basic concept.

It has:

- A dictionary keyed on a 2-tuple of input and output types to hold converter instances.
- A `Register` method to use for registering converters.  Registering the same pair of types overwrites a previously registered converter.  You can easily change it to be a no-op or an exception.
- A `Convert` method to call a registered converter.  It would be very trivial to create a `TryConvert` method if you needed it.

```cs
public static class ConverterContainer
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<(Type, Type), Delegate> _converters = new Dictionary<(Type, Type), Delegate>();

    public static void Register<TInput, TOutput>(Func<TInput, TOutput> converter)
    {
        if (converter is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(converter));

        _converters[(typeof(TInput), typeof(TOutput))] = converter;
    }

    public static TOutput Convert<TInput, TOutput>(TInput input)
    {
        if (_converters.TryGetValue((typeof(TInput), typeof(TOutput)), out var del))
        {
            Func<TInput, TOutput> converter = (Func<TInput, TOutput>)del;

            return converter(input);
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Converter not registered.");
    }
}
```

What it *does not* have:

- thread safety.  This is left as an exercise to a serious implementor.
- possibly other things I didn't take the time to consider.

How to use it:

At startup of your application, register converters, like registering services for dependency injection.

```cs
ConverterContainer.Register<long, int>(l => (int)l);
// ... etc.
```

And wherever you want to perform conversion between a registered pair of input/output types:

```
int x = ConverterContainer.Convert<long, int>(1000L)
```

Unfortunately, you *do* have to specify both type arguments here.

---

**Addition from the OP:**

To not have to specify the input parameter type (which is kind of the point of having a dynamic list of available conversions) use the following additional method in the sample `ConverterContainer` above (as @madreflection has suggested in the comments himself) :

```
public static TOutput Convert<TOutput>(object toConvert) {
    if (toConvert is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(toConvert));

    if (Converters.TryGetValue((toConvert.GetType(), typeof(TOutput)), out Delegate conv)) {
        object o = conv.DynamicInvoke(toConvert);
        return (TOutput) o;
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Converter not registered for types: {toConvert.GetType().Name} -> {typeof(TOutput).Name}");
}
```

You can now throw in any random `object` instance and see if the conversion to your desired type is possible.

Comment: That is absolutely what I wanted to have. I was missing the usage of generic methods. And the two-tuple as a dictionary key is cool!

Comment: To avoid to specify both type argument you can use a `bool TryConvert<TIn, TOut>(TIn input, out TOut output)` method signature. Also, your implementation is full static. Maybe a singleton pattern here is preferable.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is just a demonstration of a technique that satisfies the original question, so there are plenty of "maybes" and "you-coulds". For example, *you could* implement `TOutput Convert<TOutput>(object input)` which, after throwing on `null`, uses `input.GetType()` to find the input type in place of `typeof(TInput)`. I almost included that in my answer but I decided it was out of scope because it's not related to the technique I was demonstrating. Further enhancements are left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I totally understand the limitations of the given code, this was the perfect example to get me going though

Comment: @DmitryAvtonomov: I've added the null check that I mentioned in my comment. This is critical because `toConvert.GetType()` would otherwise throw `NullReferenceException`. Be sure to integrate that into your own copy of it.

Answer (score 3):

In C# all the converters in the list will share the same type parameters (`TInput`, `TOutput`). Unless you have a non generic interface `IConverter`, you will not be able to store multiple converter in anything else than a list of object.

You can anyway try to cast the elements into what you need like it is done here (with a dictionary). [Hirerate trough an heterogeneous and type-safe dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561155/hirerate-trough-an-heterogeneous-and-type-safe-dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.

You have to make a `Generic Method` or `Generic class` like this:

```
    void MyMethod<TInput, TOuput>()
    {
        List<Converter<TInput, TOuput>> myList = new List<Converter<TInput, TOuput>>();
    }
```